# SQLITE DATA NOT CHECKING DATA PRESENT ALWAYS GIVES RETURNS FALSE?

Tags: android, sqlite

***NOT GETTING DATA RETURN TRUE***

```
public boolean checkWhetherDataPresentorNot(String question_id, String selected_option, String session_id) {

    Log.d(" CHECKDATA ", "Question Id" + question_id);
    Log.d("CHECKDATA ", "Selected_option " + selected_option);
    Log.d("CHECKDATA", "Session ID " + session_id);

    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TEST_START, new String [] {QUESTION_ID_TEST_START, SELECTED_OPTION_TEST_START,TEST_START_ID}, "question_id_test_start = ? AND selected_option_test_start = ? AND test_start_id = ?",
            new String[] { question_id, selected_option, session_id },
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("CHECKDATA ", "DATA IS PRESENT");
        return true;
    }else{
        Log.d("CHECKDATA ","DATA NOT PRESENT");
        return false;
    }


}
```

#### DATA IS NOT INSERTING OR SELECT QUERY IS WRONG?

How to make data insert into sqlite database fast and read

Comment: Where is your logcat?

Comment: You can use https://objectbox.io/ for an easy and fast database.

Comment: Any other options i am using SQLite if i change the version of DATABASE_VERSION   from 1 to 3 or 4 will it work